# How to change Fixed to top Navigation to Static top without space?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use a static navbar with a header over it. My current website used fixed-top navbar, I changed the classes to static but now I have a space over my navbar: http://image.prntscr.com/image/f206622fba84476d9c2491f9f041fd4f.png

Here is the bootstrap code: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11827342/startbootstrap-bare-gh-pages_.rar.html

What cause this space? And how can I fix it?

Cheers,
CabCon

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11827318/startbootstrap-bare-gh-pages.rar.html

Comment: In your given document, there is no space is showing.

Comment: Change navbar-fixed-top -> navbar-static-top

Comment: Here is it with static-top: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11827342/startbootstrap-bare-gh-pages_.rar.html

Comment: You are required to post a relevent, minimal example of the problem here and not some third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow, helping no one in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will pay attention on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
body 
{
     padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah there is also a explanation and I searched and searched in the css.... Thank you!